# Keep a second div visible if the mouse is over the first or second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

There are two divs; Div A (`display:none` by default) and Div B (visible all the time). How would one make it so if mouse moves over Div B, Div A becomes visible. Div A should remain visible if the mouse cursor is on either Div A or Div B, otherwise Div A should be hidden.

I'm using jQuery plugin hoverIntent for this.

```
$(".the-dropdown").hoverIntent( function(){
        $(".the-dropdown").show();
    }, function(){
        $(".the-dropdown").hide();
});

$(".menu-item").hoverIntent( function(){
    $(".the-dropdown").show();
}, function(){
    $(".the-dropdown").hide();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85svp/)

Comment: Try hover instead of hoverIntent.

Comment: @Chad no luck. it still disappears instantly.

Comment: it works. I just didn't try it well. cancel my 1st comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, try something like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#a {
    background: #0f0;
    display: none;
}
#b {
    background: #f0f;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#a, #b').hover(function() {
    $('#a').show(); 
}, function() {
    $('#a').hide();    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9apd/1/)

Or in your specific case:

```
$(".the-dropdown, .menu-item").hover( function(){
        $(".the-dropdown").show();
    }, function(){
        $(".the-dropdown").hide();
});
```

Comment: that was the very first solution I came up with, but I was using `hoverIntent`. Why didn't I use this for the first time? I believe that I need some sleep. Thanks for your quick response and quick edits. Well appreciated.

Comment: @chad fyi hoverIntent is a rather useful little plugin

Answer (score 1):

> hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts to determine the user's
>   intent... like a crystal ball, only with mouse movement! It is similar
>   to jQuery's hover method. However, instead of calling the handlerIn
>   function immediately, hoverIntent waits until the user's mouse slows
>   down enough before making the call.
>
> Why? To delay or prevent the accidental firing of animations or ajax
>   calls. Simple timeouts work for small areas, but if your target area
>   is large it may execute regardless of intent. That's where hoverIntent
>   comes in...

If you would like to use the hoverIntent plugin you can download it here:
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

**[Working Example Using hoverIntent](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Z9apd/4/)**

```
$(".menu-item").hoverIntent({
    over: function () {
        $(".the-dropdown").slideDown();
    },
    out: function () {
        $(".the-dropdown").slideUp();
    },
    timeout: 500,
    interval: 500
});

<div class="menu-item">Hover this for half a second
    <div class="the-dropdown"></div>
</div>

div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.the-dropdown {
    background: red;
    display: none;
    position:relative;
    top:182px;
}
.menu-item {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem has been solved, however, the example you gave is not working as per my requirements. When you move the cursor over the blue then red shows up. When you move the cursor straight from the blue to the red then the red should remain there and should not slide up and down. Thanks for you effort. I really appreciate this.