# Display the second div after some delay and keep the second div visible if the mouse is over the first or second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In context to the previous question:-

[Keep a second div visible if the mouse is over the first or second div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882876/keep-a-second-div-visible-if-the-mouse-is-over-the-first-or-second-div)

How one would make it so the second div is displayed after some delay *(that's 1 second)* and then keep the div visible if the mouse is over the first or second div.

I've made some progress, but it's not working. Why is it not working?

Current progress :-

```
var display = false;

$(".the-dropdown, .menu-item").hover(function () {    
    display = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        show_sub_menu($(this));
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    display = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
        hide_sub_menu($(this));
    }, 1000);    
});

function show_sub_menu(obj) {
    //alert(obj); // debugging
    if (display === true) {
        obj.show();
    }
}

function hide_sub_menu(obj) {
    if (display === false) {
        obj.hide();
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85svp/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are seeking answer to this question:-

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85svp/2/)

```
var display = false;
$(".the-dropdown, .menu-item").hover(function () {    
    display = true;
    setTimeout(function () {        
        if (display === true) {            
            $('.the-dropdown').show();
        }
    }, 300);
}, function () {    
    display = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (display === false) {            
            $('.the-dropdown').hide();
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY This : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/wBvAA/)**

```
$('.menu-item , .the-dropdown').hover(
    function(){
               $("div.the-dropdown").delay('1000').show();
              }
    , function(){
              $("div.the-dropdown").delay('1000').hide();
              }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The correct solution that was required is here:- http://jsfiddle.net/85svp/2/

Comment: @OmarTariq try my new answer,it's more simple than yours

Comment: when I move my mouse cursor over the div A. The div B shows up instantly. I'm sorry if I'm not clear in my words. But the required behaviour is that when I move the mouse over div A then it should wait for at least 1 second before the Div B shows below A. And when the mouse is on neither A or B then B should hide it self instantly. Thanks